# FTP Server issue - too many clients in TIME_WAIT

Tags: tcp, ftp, time-wait

We have a piece of software which includes a version of an Apache FTP server. It accepts transmitted images and stores them. However, at some point, the images stop getting transmitted. I did a "netstat" command and found over 3k connections in a "TIME_WAIT" state - and none in established. The connections in time_wait would expire, only to be replaced by others. The time_wait is on the client side, meaning the client is the one actively closing the connection, which would mean a passive server. I believe the client must be retying, but is somehow locked out by the amount of expiring connections. This could be limited to a variable named something like "max_ftp_connections" on the server.

Can anyone shed some light on this? From what I've googled, one potential connection is to use "SO_LINGER" and the client side - but I don't have access to that code. Any ideas are welcome, though.

Comment: So you have one client with 3K ports in TIME_WAIT state?

Comment: Four clients. It's the Apache Mina server.